# Notification Center on iOS 6 is not removing deleted emails

Tags: mail.app, iphone, notifications, ios

After upgrading to iOS 6 on my 4S i'm seeing that after I delete an email in the mail app itself, it was SUPPOSED to remove it from notification center.

Now even after i've deleted messages *without* reading them from the mail app, they are STILL in notification center and I have to clear them *OR* I wait until another email comes in to clear out the ones that were already previously deleted from the mail app which removes them from the notification center.

If I open them, then they go away from the notification center.

I shouldn't need to open emails to remove them from the notification center.

Then, when I click the previously deleted email within notification center that is no longer in the mail app, it just leads me to the start screen in Mail that shows my inboxes and accounts. It doesn't do anything. It doesn't open anything because the email was deleted.

Why is this happening? Is anyone else having the same problem?

Comment: Same problem. I guess it is a "feature". Notifications across all devices, platforms and services are not really mature. (Boxcar, Growl etc. make it only worse IMHO...) Or did you ever notice how on facebook even if you see a message on your mobile or browser app, they still show up when you visit facebook.com? And obviously facebook is unable to and will never delete the e-mail notifications it sent you after you read the item you were notified upon. It's a technical problem. Bring it to the attention of Apple.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that should be fixed, but possibly also a feature request.

The problem is simple. iOS **won't** remove notification from notification center when the app that post the notification launches. The developer has to tell the app to do it in order to clear all notification at app launch.

While this behavior is expected by user, developer might want finer control over when to clear the notification.

So, Mail doesn't clear the notification, and posted notification cannot be removed by app. And that ultimately result in this weird notification that links to a deleted email.

You should file a bug at [Apple Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/wa/signIn).

Answer (score 0):

You can set your iPhone to automatically check your email periodically, which will also update the mail client and notification center on which messages have been deleted.

Visit *Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Fetch New Data > Fetch Every 15 Minutes* for the most rapid possible updating. (Note there is a battery life tradeoff.)